# Как сравнить текущее время и время создания файла в PHP?

Tags: php, кэширование

Имеется следующий php-код для создания кэш-файла:

```
<?php
$cacheFile="cities.html";
$str = file_get_contents('http://url');

if (!file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    file_put_contents("cities.html", $str, FILE_APPEND); //if file doesn't exists, create it
} else {

};
```

В случае, если файл существует, но последнее изменение было **не сегодня**, то необходимо повторно выполнить запрос по адресу из переменной $str и сохранить результат в файл. Если файл существует, но последнее изменение было **сегодня**, необходимо получить список городов из файла.
Насколько я знаю, реализовать можно через проверку разницы между текущим временем и временем создания файла. Как это реализовать?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$cacheFile="cities.html";
$str = file_get_contents('http://url');

if (!file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    file_put_contents("cities.html", $str, FILE_APPEND); //if file doesn't exists, create it
} else {
    $difference = time() - filemtime($cacheFile); //seconds
    echo "С последнего изменения прошло " . date("d H:i:s.", $difference);
};
```

[filemtime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php) [time](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)

Comment: Помогло, благодарю за ответ!